# Predict with new random effects

Tags: r, predict, lme4

When fitting a mixed effects model (or any other model), it's often useful to predict "counterfactual" fitted values, using new data or new model parameters. In my situation, I would like to predict fitted values with new random effects.

The `lme4` package allows one to insert new parameters to be used in place of the `beta`, `theta` and `sigma` slots of the `merMod` class. This would allow one to predict fitted values under counterfactual fixed effects coefficients. How can I do the same for the random effects estimates?

My first thought was to directly modify the `u` slot of the `merMod` object, but that doesn't seem to do anything. What can I do?

Example code:

```
library(lme4)

# use sleepstudy example
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)

# estimate predictions
fm1Predictions <- predict(fm1)

# estimate predictions with new fixed effects (arbitrarily set to 10)
cfPredictions <- predict(fm1, newparams=list('theta'=10)) # different than fm1Predictions

# estimate predictions with new random effects
fm2 <- fm1
fm2@u <- rep(10,length(fm2@u))
fm2Predictions <- predict(fm2) # same as fm1Predictions
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail - do you want to specify the coefficient for an individual grouping level, or do you want to specify/modify the parameter that defines the distribution of the grouping the terms?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The former. I want to specify a new vector of coefficients for individual grouping levels (`fm@u`), like I show in the second to last line of the example. I want to "pretend" that instead of the estimated group-level coefficients, there were different group-level coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it might work in the meantime.

Using `merTools` you can return the components of a predicted value from a multilevel model in a `data.frame`.

```
library(merTools)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
predInt2 <- predictInterval(fm1, which = "all", seed = 8231,
                        include.resid.var = TRUE)
```

Specifying `which = "all"` means that the components of the predicted value are returned in addition to the full predicted value.

```
predInt2[predInt2$obs == 3,]
```

Returns:

```
      effect       fit       upr         lwr obs
3   combined 313.16116 353.33704 268.5411738   3
183  Subject  40.02862  83.56716  -0.8552207   3
363    fixed 272.02953 313.85544 230.8799770   3
```

This `data.frame` shows you the predicted value for observation 3 from the `sleepstudy` data broken down by the random component for `Subject`, the `fixed` component, and the combined.

You could recompute the `combined` effect by summing the `fixed` effect and some counterfactual value for `Subject`. This is not directly supported by a function in R, but with a little data manipulation you can do:

```
counter_fact <- predInt2[predInt2$effect == "fixed", ]
counter_fact$est <- counter_fact$fit + 20
head(counter_fact)
```

And now you have an estimated value if the random component was constant with an effect of 20 for all observations.

Comment: Interesting. Which version of `merTools` are you using? I don't see an option for `which` in `predictInterval` here http://127.0.0.1:22608/library/merTools/html/predictInterval.html (and I get the error "unused argument (which="all") )

Comment: Update to version 0.3.0 or use the development version. I'm the package author so I'm always using the dev version :-)